# How to generate hash signature?

Tags: java, android, twilio, twilio-api

I am using twilio sdk to integrate sms verification with my android app, twilio asks me to register hash signature of my app and non of ways to generate hash signature worked, always says it is invalid hash signature 
this is the path that twilio wants the hash signature

[image: diagram here]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User below command in terminal of android studio to generate release key hash

```
keytool -exportcert -alias [aliasname] -keystore [your app keystore path] | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

And below code in your project to get development key hash

```
try {
    android.content.pm.PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "com.apps.sonictonic",
            android.content.pm.PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        java.security.MessageDigest md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        android.util.Log.d("KeyHash", "KeyHash:" + android.util.Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
                android.util.Base64.DEFAULT));

    }
} catch (android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this method in your Activity onCreate() and 
Search your key in logcat using key "HashKey"

```
public static void printHashKey(Context pContext) {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            String hashKey = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
            Log.d("HashKey", "printHashKey() Hash Key: " + hashKey);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have opted your app into Google Play managed signing, then you need to use a different set of steps to get the correct signature hash.

[How to configure Signature Hash with Google Play Signing · Issue #1550 · AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/1550#issuecomment-962629868)